# Conditional probability of event A given events B and C occur? Events B and C are independent from each other

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, mathematical-statistics

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$Trying to figure out the probability of the following $\P(A|B,C)$ while knowing that $B$ and $C$ are independent.

I know $\P(A|B) = \P(A \cap B)/\P(B)$.

I saw this link: [How can I calculate the conditional probability of several events?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/how-can-i-calculate-the-conditional-probability-of-several-events)

But I can't figure out how to do $\P(A \cap B \cap C)$ because $B$ and $C$ are independent. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Context** (simplified): 
Trying to find the probability that Bob will buy product $X$ (event $A$) given a few independent factors, for example: Probability that Bob wants it enough to buy it (event $B$) and probability that product $X$ works (event $C$).

So if there is a high probability that he wants it enough to buy it, $\P(A|B)$ aka the probability Bob buys product $X$ given he wants it bad enough is high. Same goes with $\P(A|C)$. Now I want to see how both independent events $B$ and $C$ affect the probability that Bob buys product $X$.

Comment: if this is HW please consider adding the [`self-study`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag

Comment: Have you tried to use the definition $$P(A|B\cap C)=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}$$

Comment: It's not hw :/ But I dont think that definition would work because B and C are independent.. right? or would the denominator just be P(B)*P(C)?

Comment: _In general_, the independence of $B$ and $C$ does not help in finding the conditional probability of an _arbitrary_ event $A$ given that $B\cap C$ occurred because it may well be that $P(A\cap B\cap C) = 0$ even though $P(A\cap B) > 0$ and $P(A\cap C) > 0$, that is, $P(A\mid B)>0$ and $P(A\mid C)>0$ but $P(A\mid B\cap C)=0$. For example, suppose that $A$ is a subset of $B^c\cap C^c = (B\cap C)^c$, say $A=(B\cap C^c)\cup(B^c\cap C)$. Then, $P(A\cap B). P(A\cap C) >0$ but $P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(\emptyset)=0$.

Comment: For your proof, you'd like to perform steps like $\mathbb{P}(B,C|A)=\mathbb{P}(B|A)\mathbb{P}(C|A)$ ... but sadly that would be *wrong* because it is not true in general that $B\perp\!\!\!\perp C \implies B\perp\!\!\!\perp C | A$ (where $\perp\!\!\!\perp$ means "is independent of").  See wikipedia's [rules of conditional independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence#Rules_of_conditional_independence).