# how to calculate conditional probablity when one even'ts occurance is dependent on mutiple events

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, bayes-rule

I have X, Y, and Z all as binary variables, values either 0 or 1. Y and Z are and got values of P(Y =
1), P(Z = 1), P(X = 1|Y = 1, Z = 1) , P(X = 1|Y = 1, Z = 0) and P(X = 1|Y = 0). here I need to compute P(X = 1)

I learned here I need to apply the concepts of  law of total probability, conditional probability, and joint probability.

By reading through below link, I get to know how to calculate P(A| B, C, D)-

[How can I calculate the conditional probability of several events?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/how-can-i-calculate-the-conditional-probability-of-several-events)

I also got to know, this would be the formula -
P(X = 1) = P(X = 1|Y = 1, Z = 1)P(Y = 1)P(Z = 1) + P(X = 1|Y = 1, Z = 0)P(Y = 1)P(Z = 0) + P(X = 1|Y = 0)P(Y = 0)

however, I haven't got any reference for this formula, do anyone has any reference for this or would be able to derive this?

Comment: It might help you to explain to use what exactly you mean by "several events."  After all, aren't you just describing a *single* event given by the conjunction of $(B,C,D)$?

Comment: As I mentioned I have gone through the link I added in my question, however that link doesn't have any reference how to calculate P(X=1) when other values are given

Comment: Consider the case of two variables $X$ and $Y$.  Suppose you know the probabilities for $(X,Y)$ equal to $(0,0),$ $(1,0),$ $(0,1),$ and $(1,1).$  Notice that the event $X=1$ is the disjoint union of the events $(X,Y)=(1,0)$ and $(X,Y)=(1,1).$  Apply an appropriate probability axiom to obtain the answer.  It's no different with more variables.